# Generate Concurrent Program Parameter LOV Dynamically

Tags: plsql, oracle-ebs

I have a concurrent program with one parameter, whereby the LOV for this parameter can only be generated at runtime through a package function. Is it possible to do so? Can the Special Validation Value Sets be used in this case?

Comment: LOV is always generated via a query. I haven't seen any instance, where its generated via package. Also, when we create LOVs using FP, we always generate it via a single query. How will a package return a list of values in the first place

Comment: That is why i ask whether it is possible to generate the LOV in runtime. My function is returning a table type collection which declared within package.

Comment: Yes if I understand the query you can pass the parameter dynamically to the packaged function and call it that way. Select * from table(PKG.function(<Param>));

Comment: In E-Business Suite, LOVs for Concurrent Program parameters are created as queries always. When you define the LOV however, you can use a View, which calls a function, for every row of the table on which it selects. If you give us an example of how the data could be generated with some concrete figures, we might be able to help.